# Difficulty in programming a regression example in NVIDIA DIGITS with CSV files

Tags: python, csv, regression, linear-regression, digits

From this example,

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/regression

I've test_lmdb_creator.py. What I'm trying to do is a *.py capable of load a CSV file like this:

```
469;class_1
480;class_1
480;class_2
471;class_3
...
```

It's a huge file with millions of rows. So, I need to take some rows and make a train_db, val_db and test_db with these rows.

I'm having a lot of difficulty to program this in Python, trying to modify test_lmdb_creator.py for my needs. For each image, the x and y (normalized) gradients are chosen randomly from a uniform distribution [-0.5,0.5) at this piece of code from test_lmdb_creator.py:

```
for i in xrange(image_count):
            xslope, yslope = np.random.random_sample(2) - 0.5
```

I've to get some numeric values from CSV file and put in the place of this uniform distribution. After that, I've to "link" the labels from CSV file too (class_1, classe_2, etc) for each respective numeric value, spliting some for train_db and others for val_db. The test_db I've already modified for n images, because the original test_lmdb_creator.py creates only one test image. But it has the same line code that needs to be changed:

```
xslope, yslope = 0.5, 0.5
```

These 0.5, 0.5 have to come from the rest of numeric values from CSV file that aren't in use for train_db and val_db. I've already did a list with all numeric values and classes from CSV file in Python but I don't know how to "pass" them through the xslopes and yslopes and "link" the labels (or classes) for each value. Do you have any tips or suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: What have you attempted to do so far?

Comment: Sorry for the time. I've modified the question.